# Display Image entity in XML through webservice(SOAP) using C#?

Tags: c#, database, web-services

There is an web application, where in it has few entities including image entity.That image is already stored in DB, now i have to access it through webservice and display in XML. Tried converting that image entity to byte[] and as well as String base64. But did not work out. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing issue transmitting the image back?

I converted the image to base64 and returned as a string. It is working fine. What issue did you face there.

But this approach requires update on the `maxReceivedMessageSize` parameters in WCF service as well as the client.

> Side effects : There are some issues with increasing
>   `maxReceivedMessageSize`. More memory foot print, might open up DDOS
>   attacks.

**Service Contract**

```
    public class ImageService : IImageService
    {
        public string GetImageData(string path)
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                return ConvertFile(path);
            }
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }

        private string ConvertFile(string path)
        {
            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(path))
            {
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                    byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

                    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                    return base64String;
                }
            }
        }        
    }
```

**Service Configuration**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" 
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                 maxArrayLength="200000000"
                 maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Client Code**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ImageService.ImageServiceClient client = new ImageService.ImageServiceClient();
        string data = client.GetData(@"C:\Users\v-sridve\Pictures\Travel_Error_New.PNG");
    }
```

**Client Configuration**

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" maxBufferSize="1000000" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:7541/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ImageService.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"  />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I too converted in base64 and passed. but that entity itself is not getting displayed on xml.

Comment: @Android-Learner please add more details with code reg what you tried. I am not understanding entity, xml here.